# How to make javascript module pattern work with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, design-patterns, module-pattern

I am trying to convert some javascript/jquery code to be able to handle ajax tabs.

I have all my scripts load up when the pages loads up and I use jquery live and livequery plugin to help with the binding.

Each time is in a partial view(asp.net mvc 3) and when clicked goes to a controller action and renders the partial view and sticks it in the tab.

So the live and livequery are solving most of the problems except for this one problem. I am using the jquery datatables.net plugin and once it renders that I store it in a variable and use it places.

The thing is since I am using the module pattern the code runs long before the table is even rendered. So the variable storing the object is "undefined". I tried to wrap it around with jquery livequery statement and that makes the table run but the variable is still "undefined".

My guess is that is not like C# were it would update the reference. So I am thinking that it is in my global variable(the one for the module pattern) and that never gets updated.

```
var tab = (function (my, $)
{
    var myTable = my.dataTable = my.dataTable || {};

    myTable.oDataTable = {};


    myTable.init = function ()
    {
        myTable.oDataTable = _fnSetupTable();
        _fnCreateDateFilters();
    };



    myTable.delete= function (rowToDelete)
    {
        // Need to get the position of the row. Need to use index
        var pos = this.oDataTable.fnGetPosition(rowToDelete[0]);

        /* delete row from table - first param is index of row */
        this.oDataTable.fnDeleteRow(pos, null, true);
    };

    function _fnSetupTable()
    {

        /* Initialize datatable object */

        $('#table').livequery(function ()
        {
            // oDataTable gets used in alot of places later on but since it undefined
            // it will crash when used.
            var oDataTable = $(this).dataTable(
            {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aaSorting": [[3, 'asc']],  //Default sorting on datetime
                "oLanguage":
                    {
                        "sZeroRecords": "No Records"
                    },
                "aoColumns":
                    [
                        { "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": false }, 
                        {"bSortable": true, "bSearchable": false }, 
                        {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false }, 
                        {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false }, 
                        {"iDataSort": 3 },
                        { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": true },  
                        {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },      
                        {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false}  
                    ]
            });

            return oDataTable;
        });

    }

    return my;

} (tab || {}, jQuery));
```

I use oDataTable quite a bit. As you can see if I would call up myTable.Delete I use it oDataTable there but it will be "undefined" and crash.

I have another module class that starts the whole sequence(so makes the above code run)

```
/* 
*   Document Ready
*/
$(function ()
{

    /* Initializes all plugins and events */
    tab.init();

});


var tab = (function (my, $)
{

    my.init = function ()
    {
        tab.preload();
        tab.dataTable.init();
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    };



return my;

} (tab || {}, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a number of things you're calling `oDataTable` and they are all assigned/accessed in incompatible ways.

The first problem I see is that the `oDataTable` value you attempt to return from `_fnSetupTable` is actually scoped to and returned from the *inner* function, so the following assignment does nothing:

```
myTable.oDataTable = _fnSetupTable();
```

You're trying to use the result of `_fnSetupTable` but _`fnSetupTable` doesn't actually return anything, its inner function does.

Perhaps a larger problem is how you're using the module pattern. I'll try to create a small example to demonstrate the problem:

```
var input = {
    dataTable: "tab table"
}

var tab = (function (my, $)
{
    // this var is local
    var myTable = my.dataTable = my.dataTable || {};

    // creating a property on a local variable
    myTable.oDataTable = {};

    // this is what's returned, but it has no access to myTable
    return my;

} (input));

console.log(tab) // does not have an oTableData property
```

As in your example a local variable called `myTable` is created and given the table properties, but what's being returned is `my`, not `myTable`. If you want those properties to be accessible from the `my` object that's returned, then you need to assign them to `my`. Or maybe you meant to return `myTable`?

Comment: if I do that won't I lose scope then? I mean I need to call it that in the delete and if it is in that function won't it not be seen?

Comment: @chobo2 - I've edited to try to make the actual problem more clear. The point is that `var oDataTable = $(this).dataTable()` is creating a variable that's local to the function given to `livequery` and the `return` statement is returning from *that* function, not from `_fnSetupTable`.

Comment: @chobo2 - Not sure about your scope question. It sounds like you're a little confused about variable scope in the module pattern and maybe JavaScript in general.